# Add a value to an empty key in a created dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

so I basically need to add a value From a txt file to the keys in output_dic and be in the following format for both years

the idea is to get data from a txt that's organised in rows and columns and procese it to get the data organised in the following output

```
                                        2020                 2021        
Max Volume (Date)                       'value added'       'value2 added'
Min Volume (Date)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time     
import pandas as pd


def main(): 
    
    again = "y"     
    
    while again.lower() == 'y' or again.lower() == "yes":
    
    
    
        output_dic = {'Max Volume (Date)': ["", "", ""],
                  'Min Value (Date)' : ["" , "", ""],
                  'Lowest Open (Date)' : ["", "", ""] ,
                  'Highest Close (Date)' : ["", "", ""],
                  'Highest Monthly Average (Months)' : ["", "" , ""],
                  'Lowest Monthly Average (Months)' : ["", "", ""],
                  'Annual Average (Months)' : ["", "", ""]}
    
        print("\n{:^91}\n".format("Apple Stock Analysis 2020 and 2021"))
        print("{:^31} {:^20} {:^20}" .format(" ", "2020", "2021" , "total"))
        print("-" * 91)
        
        
        for k, v in output_dic.items():
                y2020, y2021, y2022 = v 
                print( "{:<31} {:^20} {:^20} {:^20}" .format(k , y2020, y2021, y2022))
        break
    
    
    output_dic.update({'Max Volume (Date)' :  })
    
    print(output_dic)
```

Comment: You can supply an empty string or 0 as a key, but not nothing.With `a = {}` `a[''] = 'empty string'` and `a[0] ='zero'` are valid but `a[] = 'nothing'` throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add values to a dictionary by simply assigning the values to a keys, if for example a key already exists, then the new value would replace the old one, for example:

```
output_dic['Max Volume (Date)'] = [0, 1, 2]
```

Just to be complete I would write a sample code snippet on how to replace values read from a .txt file with values already assigned in a dictionary:

```
output_dic = {'Max Volume (Date)': ["", "", ""],
                'Min Value (Date)' : ["" , "", ""],
                'Lowest Open (Date)' : ["", "", ""] ,
                'Highest Close (Date)' : ["", "", ""],
                'Highest Monthly Average (Months)' : ["", "" , ""],
                'Lowest Monthly Average (Months)' : ["", "", ""],
                'Annual Average (Months)' : ["", "", ""]}

keys_list = ['Max Volume (Date)', 'Min Value (Date)', 'Lowest Open (Date)', 'Highest Close (Date)', 'Highest Monthly Average (Months)', 'Lowest Monthly Average (Months)', 'Annual Average (Months)']

input_file_address = 'E://file_name.txt'

with open(input_file_address, 'r') as input_file:
    index = 0
    for line in input_file:
        line_stripped = line.strip() # .txt files' lines usually end with \n and they could also have whitespace at the beginning by mistake, this line removes these issues
        
        if line_stripped == '': # if the line is empty, move to the next line
            continue
        
        line_splitted = line_stripped.split(' ') # If the values are separated by whitespace, this line would convert a string of for example 'a b c' to a list of ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
        
        key = keys_list[index]

        output_dic[key] = line_splitted

        index += 1

print(output_dic)
```

> Assuming the .txt file is formatted as below:
>
> value_1, value_2, value_3 .........................
> .........................
>
> where each line corresponds to a different parameter for example "Min
> Value" and so on.

And finally I would like to make a recommandations:
I think .txt is not a suitable file format for these types of operations, I personally prefer .csv, it's easier to parse since the formatting is unversal, unlike a .txt file where anyone can write anything in any format.

Comment: The format is:        
Date.   Opening. Closing.                                (Val1).  (Val2).     (Val3).                       Etc. Basically I have 592 rows and 7 columns with header

Comment: If I understand correctly every line is a different date with multiple values related to that date and then you'd perform a few operations on them to get the information that you specified in 'output_dic' (sorry about poor English btw). I do this stuff all the time and I use 'Pandas' but if you don't know how my suggeston is to first read the file line by line and store each line as a list and then combine all the lists and perform your operation, without Pandas it's gonna get crazy but I've done worse so it's possible, good luck. If you needed more help tell me, I could help out through email